# Postgres won't accept table alias before column name

Tags: sql, postgresql, jodd

I'm using a framework (Jodd) which is adding the table alias to the column names in a SQL Select.  It looks like well-formed SQL, but Postgres chokes on it.

```
update GREETING Greeting 
     set Greeting.ID=5, 
         Greeting.NAME='World', 
         Greeting.PHRASE='Hello World!'  
where (Greeting.ID=5)
```

gives an error:

```
Error: ERROR: column "greeting" of relation "greeting" does not exist
SQLState:  42703
```

Is there a way to get Postgres to accept that SQL?  My other alternative is to hack the framework, which I don't want to do.

Comment: Have you tried setting different column name aliasing mode (http://jodd.org/doc/db/sqlgenerator.html#Column-name-aliasing)? By default TABLE_REFERENCE is set - that will add table aliases for columns, but you can try other two. This can be set by DbOomManager#setDefaultColumnAliasType() method, somewhere at the application startup. Also, don't hesitate to contact Jodders with the real code snippet, they are willing to help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the latest Jodd, v3.3.7. where this issue is fixed.

The problem was in the Jodd library: entity update methods were generating update statement with table aliases. The new version simply does not put table aliases; that works for Postgres and for other databases too.

Answer (score 63):

The problem is that you include the table alias in `SET` clause, in the columns. See the documentation of [`UPDATE` in Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html):

> *`column`*
>
> The name of a column in *`table`*. The column name can be qualified with a subfield name or array subscript, if needed. Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column — for example, **`UPDATE tab SET tab.col = 1`** is invalid.

This is valid in Postgres:

```
update GREETING Greeting 
set 
    NAME='World', 
    PHRASE='Hello World!' 
where Greeting.ID=5 ;
```

Comment: Maybe, you do not need to specify table name since SET works with target table only?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНоздрев are you asking why that limitation exists? Yeah, I suppose it has to do with that only one table can be updated in an UPDATE statement. But it is a limitation, I think the standard allows you to use `SET tablename.column = ` so it will be fixed at som epoint (or maybe it has already been fixed, I have to check)

Comment: This solution was perfect to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Check documentation on [`UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html) statement, specifically for the ***column*** part: it is illegal to prefix columns with table alias in the `SET` clause.

```
UPDATE GREETING Greeting
   SET ID=5, NAME='World', PHRASE='Hello World!'
 WHERE (Greeting.ID=5);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it is illegal with postgres to use an alias for the name of the column that is being updated but note that it is possible (and sometimes necessary) to use an alias in the rhs expression. For instance:

```sql
CREATE TABLE greetings (name VARCHAR(20), phrase VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO greetings (name, phrase);
VALUES ('palindrome_1', 'Rise to vote sir'),
       ('palindrome_2', 'Race fast, safe car');

-- You can do something like this:
UPDATE greetings g SET phrase = REVERSE (g.phrase);
                                      -- ^
                                      -- |
                                      -- +--- this works
```

This is a bit silly in this example because we don't need that alias. This becomes more useful when multiples tables are involved.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. You can't use them in the left-hand sides of `SET` clauses. You should try to find a way to prevent Jodd from adding them there.

I think table aliases are most useful in `UPDATE`s when you're updating data from another table, because such queries tend to be lengthier than single-table updates, yet no other answer gives an example of that.

The important thing to remember is that target fields in the `SET` clause need not be named at all. So yes, you can indeed use the prefixes; just omit them from the `SET` target field(s), and everything works.

The following is valid:

```sql
UPDATE my_target_table_with_a_long_name t
  SET (target_field_a, target_field_b) = (s.source_field_a, s.source_field_b)
FROM my_source_table_with_another_long_name s
WHERE t.id = s.target_id;
```

Note how table aliases are used everywhere **except** on the left-hand side of the SET clause comparison, where the table name references are simply omitted entirely.

In your case it would be better to just write the query without any aliases at all:

```sql
UPDATE "GREETING"
  SET "ID"=5, "NAME"='World', "PHRASE"='Hello World!'  
WHERE (ID=5);
```

You could add an alias and use an alias in the `WHERE` clause (e.g. `greet."ID"=5`), but as your query refers to no other tables, what exactly would be the point?