# PostgreSQL: Error: column of relation does not exist

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
UPDATE master as m
SET m.husband = p.id
From per as p
where m.drid = p.drid AND p.address > 80000 AND p.address <= 154969
```

I have a table called `per` which has column called `id`. Basically, I want to copy these ids in my another table called `master` on the `where` clause.

But I am getting an error saying, column "m" of relation "master" does not exist.
m is not a column. I am not sure where I went wrong?

Comment: Is it MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: The error is related to the clause "as m". This is not possible in this case. Furthermore it's hard to understand, what you actually want to acomplish.Try this out: `UPDATE master SET husband = (SELECT id FROM per WHERE master.drid = per.drid AND per.address > 80000 AND per.address <= 154969);`

Comment: Jan Trienes, I am trying update column id in table per same as column husband of table master on condition where drids from the both the tables are same. Btw..your suggestion worked like I wanted. Thanks

Comment: @JanTrienes: You are definitely allowed to alias tables in an `UPDATE`. What you're not allowed to do is qualify target field names in `SET` clauses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres won't accept table alias before column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369757/postgres-wont-accept-table-alias-before-column-name)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it like below rather; remove table alias `m` from `SET` operation and make it `SET husband = p.id`

```
UPDATE master m
SET husband = p.id
From per p
where m.drid = p.drid 
AND p.address > 80000 
AND p.address <= 154969
```

(OR) without using table alias at all like

```
UPDATE master 
SET husband = per.id
From per
where master.drid = per.drid 
AND per.address > 80000 
AND per.address <= 154969
```

See [Postgres Documentation For More](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html)