# updating PosgreSQL database via SQLalchemy; syntax error

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql

I have two tables in a PostgreSQL database; table1, table2. They both contain an id column. I want to add a column from table2, say col1, to table1 where table1.id = table2.id.

I am attempting to dot this via SQLalchemy. I keep getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "INNER"
```

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
engine = create_engine(...)

with engine.connect() as con:
   con.execute("ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN col1 text")
   con.execute("UPDATE table1  \
                INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id \
                SET table1.col1 = table2.col1")
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not support `UPDATE...JOIN` like MySQL and MS Access. However, Postgres does support `UPDATE...FROM` even `UPDATE...FROM...JOIN`:

```
con.execute("""UPDATE table1 t1
               SET col1 = t2.col1
               FROM table2 t2
               WHERE t1.id = t2.id""")
```

Comment: I keep getting the error: ```sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) missing FROM-clause entry for table "table2"```?

Comment: Is there a table named `table2` in database? Error is titled `UndefinedTable`.

Comment: I forgot to put the schema in front of the table name. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the joins directly while updating in postgres and the way you have joined is incorrect. Please use below query,

```
update table1 set table1.col1 = qry.col1
from
(select col1 from table2) qry
where 
table1.id = table2.qry;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct syntax for `update`.  Please see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html

```
update table1
   set col1 = table2.col1
  from table2
 where table2.id = table1.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

correct syntax for update with another table in postgresql :

```
 UPDATE table1 
 set table1.col1 = table2.col1
 FROM table2 
 where  table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: Be careful here. Postgres does not allow [target columns in `SET` to be aliased](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11370132/1422451). A frustrating and weird error for newcomers.

Comment: effectively : copy/paste error of the original resuest