# Postgres - Update table with subquery of same table says column reference is ambiguous

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table which has columns such as

```
id | due_date | sent_at | due_days | calculate_due_date
```

some of the rows have null values for column `calculated_due_date` and I want to update such rows with a calculation using the existing columns in the table using a case statement. Below is the query that I have written but I think I am getting some alias wrong, I need some help and explanation to find the issue in this query, Thanks in advance.

```
UPDATE outgoinginvoice o2
  SET o2.calculated_due_date = calculated.calculated_due_date
  FROM (SELECT o.calculated_due_date,
    CASE
        WHEN o.due_date IS NULL THEN o.sent_at + CAST(o.due_days || ' days' AS INTERVAL)
        ELSE o.due_date
    END AS calculated_due_date
    FROM outgoinginvoice as o) as calculated
    WHERE o2.calculated_due_date IS NULL
```

The error I am receiving is,

> column reference "calculated_due_date" is ambiguous

Comment: In the subquery you have two columns named ``calculated_due_date``!

Comment: You have to add a join condition between the derived table (`calculated`)  and the target table in your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE outgoinginvoice o2
  SET calculate_due_date = calculated.calculated_due_date
  FROM (select
    CASE
        WHEN o.due_date IS NULL THEN o.sent_at + CAST(o.due_days || ' days' AS INTERVAL)
        ELSE o.due_date
    END AS calculated_due_date
    FROM outgoinginvoice  o) calculated
WHERE o2.calculate_due_date IS NULL
returning *;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369757/postgres-wont-accept-table-alias-before-column-name